# Date format error on user's computer dependent

Tags: vb.net

Here is my problem. the date that i got from my database contains "12/31/2013". Based on this date, the format is mm/dd/yy. Now the question is how do i makes it that no matter what format of the date in the user's computer, they will always read the date "12/31/2013" as mm/dd/yy instead of example dd/mm/yy which when it reads it contains an error due to there is no 31 month. i try the split method on the date i receive from my database but i coudn't get it to confirm to the format that is independent from the user's computer

Answer (score 1):

Is your date being stored in your database as an actual `date` format, or as a string?

Remember that `DateTime.Parse` by default, uses the current user's current system date/time formatting settings (so UK users are dd/MM/yyyy, but US users are MM/dd/yyyy). If you want uniform parsing then use `DateTime.ParseExact` and specify an exact parsing format string.

One rule of thumb that's useful to remember is that "if you're ever using `String.Split`, you're probably doing something wrong" (I'll make exceptions for quick-and-dirty by-design programs, but for parsing a Format-string, Regular-expression, or Finite state machine is more performant (less string allocations) and less brittle.

Back on-topic, if your database is storing objects as a `date` or `datetime` then don't use strings at all. Use the `.GetDateString(int)` method of `IDataReader` or typed field properties of EF classes.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear if you want to read the same format from the database or display it on the screen (UI)

If its from the sql server, consider using [convert](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)  <- follow this link

Answer (score 0):

How did you get a date from your database?  Did you store the date as a string?  If at all possible, consider keeping the date as a `DateTime` variable rather than a string.  If not possible, look into the `DateTime.TryParse` method which supports internationalization and should be able to understand with the user's UI localization settings.